# how to call "cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig" and "cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig"

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to optimize shared memory for a cuda code on GTX 1080. To do so, I want to change the shared memory bank width and cache configuration by calling:

```
cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig(cudaSharedMemBankSizeEightByte)
```

and

```
cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferShared)
```

Where do I call these functions? Currently, I call them in a host function that uses "cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel to call a global function:

```
template< ... > bool launch_dualBlock(...){
    ...  
    gpuErrChk(cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig(cudaSharedMemBankSizeEightByte));
    gpuErrChk(cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferShared)); 
    ...
    cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel( (void*)nv_wavenet_dualBlock<...>, grid, block ... )
}
```

definition of nv_wavenet_dualBlock is:

```
template< ... > __global__ void nv_wavenet_dualBlock( ... ){
    nv_wavenet_dualBlock_A< ... >( ... );
    return;
}
```

and nv_wavenet_dualBlock_A is a device function.

However, the two function calls seem to do nothing because when I print shared memory and cache configuration after I call the two functions, the printed values indicate that nothing changed. Also, I check the return value of the two functions and they are both cudaSuccess.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these function calls have any effect on GPUs in the Maxwell or Pascal families.

This is covered in the documentation on [compute capability in the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities)

and in [the tuning guides](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#programming-guides)

Maxwell and Pascal devices do not support 8-byte bank mode.

Maxwell and Pascal devices have a different cache design such that L1 and shared memory are no longer part of the same functional unit. Therefore there is no "split" between L1 and cache, and no need/no effect to set the preference.